# Dynamic Macro Variable

Tags: macro, plugin-digitalproducts

We're using the [Digital Products](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/DigitalProducts) plugin from Pixel and Tonic to sell 6 different types of products. I've set up a macro with matching icons for each of the product types (image, video, etc). On our user account page, I want to show recent purchases with the icon of the product type underneath it.

Usually, I would write `{{ icons.image }}` or `{{ icons.video}}` to call the icon macro. But the variable needs to be dynamic if I want to display it under a dynamic list of products.

In order to make it dynamic, of course, I need to be able to inject different macro variables `image`, `video`, `etc` when they're called.

I found the `{{ attribute() }}` function, which looks like the preferred way of accessing dynamic attributes.

So I tried this:

`{{ attribute(icons, license.product.type) }}`

And get this error:

`Illegal offset type in isset or empty`

So I researched a bit and found that I could try `{{ attribute(icons, license.product.type[0]) }}`

But that led to this error: `Property "Craft\DigitalProducts_ProductTypeModel.0" is not defined.`

So, basically now I'm stuck. My lack of PHP knowledge may be holding me back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better approach would be to pass the icon as a parameter to your macro. So I would do something like

```
{% macro renderIcon(type) %}
    {% switch type %}
        {% case 'video' %}
            {% include 'video.twig' %}
        {% case 'audio' %}
            {% include 'audio.twig' %}
        {% default %}
            {% include '_generic.twig.twig' %}
    {% endswitch %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And in your template you can do

```
{% import 'macro.twig' as icon %}
{{ icon.renderIcon(product.getType().handle) }}
```